# Why start script is not working to display Hello World in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What is the issue with below script?
I cannot access the site and shows me "This site can’t be reached" error

```
 #!/bin/bash
# Use this for your user data (script from top to bottom)
# install httpd (Linux 2 version)
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd.service
systemctl start httpd.service
systemctl enable httpd
echo "<h1>Hello World from $(hostname -f)</h1>" > /var/www/html/index.html
```

Comment: From [Run commands on your Linux instance at launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html): _The cloud-init output log file (`/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`) captures console output so it is easy to debug your scripts following a launch if the instance does not behave the way you intended._

Answer (score 5):

The correct `UserData` is (you have also space at the very beginning):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Use this for your user data (script from top to bottom)
# install httpd (Linux 2 version)
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd
systemctl start httpd
systemctl enable httpd
echo "<h1>Hello World from $(hostname -f)</h1>" > /var/www/html/index.html
```

You will also need to make sure that the instance is in a public subnet, has public IP and its security group allow connections to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for response.

I don't know much about linux commands. But I did terminate the instance and created again with below user data and found working. Same user data was used earlier also but didn't worked. Also set inbound rules to allow public IP with port 80 also. But didn't work.
So finally I did terminate and recreate instance which is working.

```
#!/bin/bash
# install httpd (Linux 2 version)
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd
systemctl start httpd
systemctl enable httpd
echo "<h1>Hello World from $(hostname -f)</h1>" > /var/www/html/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers will automatically redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS and hide the protocol. When doing a simple test like this where you won't be using HTTPS due to not having a certificate, it might be required to manually edit the URL to force it back to HTTP. This was my issue.

[image]

[image]

Thus if you put your cursor in the URL bar
[image]

change that to

[image]

now you get

[image]

Also instead of the browser you can use a command like tool like curl and skip the HTTPS redirect issue.

[image: curl 34.223]